# Why it keep editing only the first note even if I click the second one?

Tags: javascript, html, css, windows, debugging

I'm trying to do a Note Taker application using HTML, CSS, Bootstrap, Javascript, with an "Edit" button for every note that I take.Everything works just fine, except that when I add 2, 3, or more notes, and I click the edit button for the 3rd one, I can edit the first one(WTF?! :)) ), it's the same when I click the 2nd one, and so on.Everytime it keeps editing only the first note.Could someone help me solve this problem, please?

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('add');

const notes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes")) || [];

function addNote() {
  const title = document.getElementById('title').value;

  const note = {
    title,
    txt,
    id: notes.length > 0 ? notes[notes.length - 1].id + 1 : 1,
  };

  notes.push(note);
  localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notes));
  showNote();
}


const showNote = () => {

  const cardBody = document.getElementById('notesCard');

  cardBody.innerHTML = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
    cardBody.innerHTML += `
                <div class = "card" style = "1px solid; margin-bottom:10px">
                <h5 class = "card-title" style = "color:#008000">${notes[i].title}</h5>
                <p class = "card-text">${notes[i].txt}</p>
                <div class = "buttons">
                <a class = "deleteButton" style = "color:#FF0000;border:1px solid red; width:50px" onclick = deleteButton(${notes[i].id})>Delete</a>
                <a class = "editButton" style = "color:#FF0000; border:1px solid red; width:50px" onclick = editButton(${notes[i].id})>Edit</a>
                <a class = "saveB" style = "color:#FF0000; border:1px solid red; width:50px; display:none" onclick = saveButton(${notes[i].id})>Save</a>
                </div>
                </div>
                `;
  }

}

showNote();

const editButton = (id) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
    if (notes[i].id === id) {
      const para = document.querySelector(".card-text");
      const editb = document.querySelector('.editButton');
      const saveB = document.querySelector('.saveB');
      para.contentEditable = "true";
      editb.style.display = "none";
      saveB.style.display = "block";
    }
  }
}

const saveButton = (id) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
    if (notes[i].id === id) {
      const para = document.querySelector(".card-text");
      const editb = document.querySelector('.editButton');
      const saveB = document.querySelector('.saveB');
      para.contentEditable = "false";
      editb.style.display = "block";
      saveB.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}

const deleteButton = (id) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
    if (notes[i].id === id) {
      notes.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }

  showNote();
  localStorage.setItem('notes', JSON.stringify(notes));
}

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  addNote();
})
```

```css
#add {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#add:hover {
  color: orange;
}

input {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
  float: left;
}

.deleteButton {
  color: rgb(3, 139, 3);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.editButton {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.saveB {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="head-container">
  <h1 class='display-3 text-center text-muted my-4'>Note Taker</h1>
</div>
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
  <div class="form-group w-50">
    <input type='text' placeholder="Title of your note" id='title'>
    <textarea class="form-control width:50% text-center" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" placeholder="Enter your text"></textarea>
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
      <button id='add'>Add Note</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <h5 class="card-header text-center">My Lists</h5>
  <div class="card-body">
    <dbody id="notesCard">

    </dbody>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, This will happen because in the code here, while creating each new element in the JS function `showNote()` we are creating similar cards for all the notes.
Now in the`editButton(${notes[i].id})`,

```
const editButton = (id) => {
for (let i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
if (notes[i].id === id) {
// THIS WILL EACH TIME RETURN THE FIRST OCCURENCE OF CLASS 'card-text', 'editButton' and 'saveB'
  const para = document.querySelector(".card-text"); 
  const editb = document.querySelector('.editButton');
  const saveB = document.querySelector('.saveB'); 
  para.contentEditable = "true";
  editb.style.display = "none";
  saveB.style.display = "block";
  }
 }
}
```

so, when you run the query selector, each time it will take the **FIRST** occurrence of the class `card-text` , `editButton` and `saveB` from the DOM i.e. why your first note is getting edited.
SO, Basically, you need to differentiate each note card for the appropriate selection.

Solution :

1. Give a unique Id (like `notes[i].id` ) to each of your card div and then get that div by Id, after that for this div you can do all sorts of manipulations. (Better one)
2. Give a unique id to each of your `card-text`and other classes like `notes[i].id + 'card-text'` and then get this element in query selector.

**Edit : Update with Code**

Add Id to each card while creation in function `showNote()` :

```
 <div  id=${notes[i].id} class = "card" style = "1px solid; margin-bottom:10px">
```

When clicking on the Edit button, access the card with its id to get specific card to edit in `editButton(id)` function

```
const editButton = (id) => {
for(let i = 0 ; i < notes.length; i++){
    if(notes[i].id === id){
        // Here we access the card with that particular id, and make changes within the classes nested in it.
        const card = document.getElementById(notes[i].id); 
        const para = card.querySelector(".card-text");
        const editb = card.querySelector('.editButton');
        const saveB = card.querySelector('.saveB');
        para.contentEditable = "true";
        editb.style.display = "none";
        saveB.style.display = "block";
    }   
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you for your answer man, could you give me an example, to make me understand better, please? I'm a bit lost here.. :(

Comment: Provide the codepen of this, I ll fix it there @AndreiAlexandrescu

Comment: codepen.io/andrei-alexandrescu/pen/rNmNVyq - There you go man, thank you in advance – @Soumil Khandelwal

Comment: Updated the answer with the solution you are looking for @AndreiAlexandrescu

Comment: happy to help! you can upvote the answer as well @AndreiAlexandrescu